# Multiple valigns in one label

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am programming a Chat Bot and I want to build a GUI using kivy. To make the chat I am using labels in a scrollview:

```
GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 0
        ScrollView:
            size: self.size
            do_scroll_x: False
            Label:
                id: msg
                text_size: self.width,None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                font_size: 20
```

Python Code:

```
def send(self,x):
    #global msgback
    self.msg_list.text += str(x + "\n")
```

The problem is, that I do not know how to make the valign, that only makes the messages from  the user on the right side. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use ***halign*** to align text to the right.

```
    Label:
        id: msg
        text_size: self.width,None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        font_size: 20
        halign: 'right'
        valign: 'middle'
```

[Label » halign](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.halign)

> ```
> halign
> ```
>
> Horizontal alignment of the text.
>
> halign is an OptionProperty and defaults to ‘left’. Available options
>   are : left, center, right and justify.
>
> Warning
>
> This doesn’t change the position of the text texture of the Label
>   (centered), only the position of the text in this texture. You
>   probably want to bind the size of the Label to the texture_size or set
>   a text_size.

Comment: But now the complete text is on the right side. I need the arguments to only apply on the text which gets input by the send function.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XKk39jvKhvEbfKtHB7R1ba0l97iNn_hP/view?usp=sharing    This is the complete code.